# VBA Word - Insert embedded image on button press

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've made a custom ribbon which contains a few buttons. These buttons are supposed to insert different kinds of symbols or pictures into the document, on the selection.

Since this is a template I would like the template to be used without a folder of images and instead have the images embedded somehow in the stucture of the document.

I have thought of two possible way this could be done.

```
1. Create a portion of the template document which contains all 
   the images and hide it somehow

2. Add the images to the zip structure of the file, in the \word\media folder
   and load the images from there. If even possible...???
```

What would be the best/easiest way to achieve this effect?

Comment: What version of Word are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it probably doesn't matter too much which version you're using (unless it's 2003/4 or before). Generally, the way to do this is by creating building blocks (or quick parts, which is what they're called in Word 2010).

This link explains the basic steps you'll take (although the details will differ if you're not using Word 2010/13): https://support.office.com/en-SG/Article/Word-2010-Create-a-new-template-cb17846d-ecec-49d4-82ea-a6f5e3e8b9ae#__toc278287931

Basically, you paste your image into a document, select it, add it to the Quick Parts/Building Blocks gallery, but save it to your template (which must be open at the time). Then, users should be able to access them from the Quick Parts button. Or, if you're inserting them programatically based on something the user does, you can do something like:

```
objTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("flower").Insert selection.Range
```